# PowerBi Filters not display correct values - TOPN

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset as below.
I have ranked profiles based on revenue.
And then I selected profiles which have ranks lower than 30 using a filter. From that 30 I wanted to filter top 5 profiles based on GP% and bottom 5 profiles based on bud diff. But the results are not correct.

[image]

Bottom 5 Profiles on Bud Diff
[image]

Top 5 based on GP%

[image]

Both results are taken under this filter

[image]

Please find the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EyL7c-LxHI2GRUFWo8ibe1jrmkXlpiEI) for .pbix file

Can Any one help me on this please?

Comment: quick question, In your question description you mentioned  `ranks higher than 30` but in your filter I see `<=30` which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Please download the [pbix file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f__jEe0YnYvocir5idL05APWHfhN3Pil/view?usp=sharing) if anybody wants to have a look.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Beware tough that using a RANKX of SUMX instead of a sum, makes your report much slower because your calculation is inefficient. For every row you are now iterating over every single row again. Might not be an issue for now, but I'd recommend you to take a second look at how they work [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax). I know these functions are tempting as they are very close to the way excel behaves, but when it becomes a habit to use iterator functions, bigger reports might go very slow very quickly.

Comment: @JelleHoekstra thank you very much for the tip. I'm still new to power bi and dax. I'll  have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the filters are acting independently of each other, they are not evaluated as AND. There is no way to do this with regular filters but you can do a little trick.

By adding the following measure to your report and by referring to it in your topn filter in the value field you can get it done. What this measure does, is that it only leaves values for the top 30 you've selected. When using that to pick the bottom 5, it limits the values it can select to the 30 clients you've filtered already.

```
IF ( [Rank] <= 30 ; SUM ( Sales[Bud Diff] ) ; BLANK() )
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I have found a solution your answer helped me to find it.